# Change different variables by function input

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how to change different variables through function input.

Lets say I have two different variables, MyX=100 and MyY=150. I want to add 10 to one of these with the help of the input to a function.

```
<button onclick="Test(MyX)"><p>Test</p></button>
<button onclick="Test(MyY)"><p>Test</p></button>
```

In the javascript I've made a third variable that I then use in calculations inside the function.

```
function Test(MyZ)
```

How do I output the original variable without having to make an if statement for each possible input variable?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `MyX` is never set here. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: MyX and MyZ are defined in a prerun script. They are presented in a table. I want to be able to change both with a single function by changing the input =)

Comment: I'm still at a loss, I think you'll have to add more code to your question. Do you mean: `MyX = MyX + 10;`?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: can you give more concrete examples of what you want to happen?  it sounds like you're confusing some terms, but i'm not sure which ones  :)

Comment: Kind of. I want the variable in the function (MyZ) being temporary declared by MyX/MyY to be used in the function. 
So:

`<button onclick="Test(MyX)"><p>Test</p></button>`
`function Test(MyZ)`
`{`
`MyZ=MyZ+10;`
`}`

increases the value of MyX by 10.

Comment: It sounds like you're confused about the concepts of scoping, function calls, and variables.  Please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the concept of arguments/method calls.

In your example:

```
<button onclick="Test(MyX)"><p>Test</p></button>
<button onclick="Test(MyY)"><p>Test</p></button>
```

What happens here is when these buttons are clicked, the function `Test` is called with whatever values `MyX` and `MyY` currently contain.  In this case, without any additional code, they would both be null.

Your lower function, defined in the `.js` file:

```
function Test(MyZ)
{
//..
//..
//..
}
```

This is a function (method).  When you call this method, it executes code according to what is passed in as a parameter.

What will happen here is that the code in Test will be called with `MyZ`'s value being `MyX` or `MyY` depending on which button is clicked.

The scoping of this prevents you from modifying a variable originally defined in your button click.  What you can do here is a `void` function, which means it is side-effects only.  You can change a class/global variable, but not a variable defined in mark up.

I hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

From your clarifying comment:

> I want the variable in the function (MyZ) being temporary declared by MyX/MyY to be used in the function. So: `<button onclick="Test(MyX)"><p>Test</p></button> function Test(MyZ) { MyZ=MyZ+10; }` increases the value of MyX by 10.

You can't do that in JavaScript.  The function receives the value passed to it, not any sort of reference to the variable that happened to contain it.

What you *can* do is add a layer of indirection.  Put all these variables in an object and pass key names instead:

```
<script>
    var my_values = {
        x: 100,
        y: 150
    };

    function test(key) {
        my_values[key] += 10;
    }
</script>

<button onclick="test('x');">test</button>
<button onclick="test('y');">test</button>
```

This is a better approach anyway, since it (slightly) reduces all the global state you have going on.  JS is much easier to reason about if you keep it out of your HTML, put your variables and functions in a single namespace, etc.

Comment: This seems like an awesome solution, but when I try to alert(key) it gives me MyStone, not its value.

`<script>
    var my_values =
  {
        MyWood: 100,
        MyStone: 150
    }
    function Test(key)
 {
  alert(key)
        my_values[key] += 10; 
}

</script>
<button onclick="Test('MyStone')"><p>Test</p></button>`

Comment: right.  `key` is the key.  :)  `my_values[key]` is the value.

Comment: I do not know why enter does not work in comments, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question but I'm going to take a stab. It sounds like you want to use a function to increment a number (X/Y/Z) and then return the original value. (It kinda defeat the purpose of the calculation but... )

```
function Test(param){
   var originalVal = param;
   var newVal = param + 10;
   return originalVal; //it would make more sense if you return the newVal here
}
```

The function takes in a parameter or whatever variable you pass in and does the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using variables as function parameters use the elementIDs as parameter

```
<input type="text" id="myx" />
<input type="text" id="myy" />

<button onclick="Test('myx')"><p>Test</p></button>
<button onclick="Test('myy')"><p>Test</p></button>

function Test(x){
document.getElementById(x).value=parseInt(document.getElementById(x).value)+10;
}
```